# Conversion between different template instantiation of the same template

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

I am trying to write an `operator` which converts between the differnt types of the same implementation. This is the sample code:

```
template <class T = int>
class A
{
public:
    A() : m_a(0){}

    template <class U>
    operator A<U>()
    {
        A<U> u;
        u.m_a = m_a; 
        return u;
    }
private:
    int m_a;
};

 int main(void)
{
    A<int> a;
    A<double> b = a;
    return 0;
}
```

However, it gives the following error for line `u.m_a = m_a;`.

> Error 2   error C2248: 'A::m_a' :
>   cannot access private member declared
>   in class
>   'A'    d:\VC++\Vs8Console\Vs8Console\Vs8Console.cpp    30  Vs8Console

I understand the error is because `A<U>` is a totally different type from `A<T>`. Is there any simple way of solving this (may be using a friend?) other than providing setter and getter methods? I am using Visual studio 2008 if it matters.

Comment: Can't you pass the value to the constructor?

Comment: @sbi: may be I can..but was wondering how to solve this, if I can't pass the value as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VC10 accepts this:

```
template <class T = int>
class A
{
public:
    template< typename U>
    friend class A;

    A() : m_a(0){}

    template <class U>
    operator A<U>()
    {
        A<U> u;
        u.m_a = m_a; 
        return u;
    }
private:
    int m_a;
};
```

Comment: works fine..I didn't know I can declare a friend with a template parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare the conversion function as friend

```
template <class T = int>
class A
{
public:
    A() : m_a(0){}

    template <class U>
    operator A<U>()
    {
        A<U> u;
        u.m_a = m_a; 
        return u;
    }

    template <class U> template<class V>
    friend A<U>::operator A<V>();
private:
    int m_a;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could construct the `A<U>` with the int directly.